# open layer GetFeatureInfo proxy setting

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, openlayers

I have problems with this line, 
          ***OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";***

What should do other than writing above line in open layer code set?

My information
  I try to get feature information of WMS image using WMSGetFeatureInfo command.I am using openlayer 2.10 ,geoserver and apache-tomcat-6.0.35.I can run tomcat using localhost:8080 and geoserver using localhost:8080/geoserver.

I am new to open layer and i see Frequently Asked Questions about the OpenLayers project but still can't figure out the answer.Yours any answers are very help full for me?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link could be useful: [Openlayers Proxy path usage](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost)

Some of the tasks that OpenLayers performs (including WFS requests) require the use of a proxy script because of restrictions in JavaScript on the use of XMLHTTPRequest making requests to remote servers. 
Add that specific declaration before setting the map.

Start from here:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/[2](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/)

Example of code:

```
    /*
     * Fix for OpenLayers using 900913 for web mercator and AGS using 102113 (it must run before map init)
    OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.prototype.getFullRequestString = function(newParams,altUrl) {
        try {
            var projectionCode=typeof this.options.projection == 'undefined' ? this.map.getProjection() : this.options.projection;
        } catch(err){
            var projectionCode=this.map.getProjection();
        }
        this.params.SRS = projectionCode=="none" ? null : projectionCode;
        return OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.prototype.getFullRequestString.apply(this,arguments);
    }

*/

    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = proxyPath;

    var options = {
        projection: mercator, //EPSG:3785/900913
        displayProjection: geographic, //EPSG:4326
        theme: null,
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
        maxResolution: 156543.0339,
        units: 'm',
        controls: [],
        numZoomLevels: MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL,
        allOverlays: true
    };
    OpenLayers.Util.DEFAULT_PRECISION = 18;

    mp = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    addMaps();
    addControls();
    mp.addLayers([googlePhysical, googleSatellite, googleStreets, googleHybrid]);
    //Enabling the preferred layers with a delay of 450 to be able to load the external backgrounds
    setTimeout(setInitialLayersDiv, 450);

    if (!mp.getCenter()) {
        if (document.getElementById('userMapExtent').value != '') {
            var sExtent = document.getElementById('userMapExtent').value.split(',');
            mp.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(sExtent[0], sExtent[1], sExtent[2], sExtent[3]), true);
        } else {
            mp.zoomToExtent(europeGoogleExtent);
        }
    }
    J('#google_loading').hide('slow');
```